# Unexpected result while using async await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new A();

        var result = a.Method();

        Console.Read();
    }
}

class A
{
    public async Task<string> Method()
    {
        await Task.Run(new Action(MethodA));
        await Task.Run(new Action(MethodB));

        return "done";
    }

    public async void MethodA()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MethodA" + i);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }

    public async void MethodB()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MethodB" + i);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

[Result Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEcnx.jpg)

[image]

I think the expectation here is first output MethodA1, MethodA2... MethodA9 and then start to output MethodB1... MethodB9.

But seems it's not. Does anyone have an explanation on this? Thanks!

---

Edit:

Thanks for the replies. Actually I know how to output the correct result but just wonder why my code behave weird as I thought it against my knowledge of async/await.

```
class A
{
    public async Task<string> Method()
    {
        await Task.Run(new Action(MethodA));

        await Task.Run(async () => {
            for (var i=0;i<10;i++)
                await Task.Delay(100);
            Console.WriteLine("should output before done");
        });

        return "done";
    }

    public async void MethodA()
    {
        var returnString = string.Empty;
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            await Task.Delay(200);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("MethodA " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    }
}
```

I simplified the code and now it's like this. The first await quickly shift control to the next await and then the second await behaves as I expected and "done" was output at last. But I don't know what made the difference here.

[Result Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8BhX.jpg)

[image]

Updates: Do remember the sample code is a bad practice. you could [read this post for more information](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-using.html)

And a friend suggested the difference is that

`await Task.Run(new Action(MethodA));`

doesn't equals

```
 await Task.Run(async () => {
            for (var i=0;i<10;i++)
                await Task.Delay(100);
            Console.WriteLine("should output before done");
        });
```

the former one invoked 'methodA' in a synchronized way while the poster one is a correct asynchronized invoke. But it still confuses me because if this is true then the asynchronized action can and only can be represented by a lambda expression. I mean, there is not a thing like 'new async Action(...)' right?

Updates:

I tried Task.Factory.StartNew(Action action) which was believed to be equivalent to Task.Run(Action action) and things changed again:

```
class A
{
    public async Task<string> Method()
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(MethodA));

        await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => {
            for (var i=0;i<10;i++)
                await Task.Delay(100);
            Console.WriteLine("should output before done");
        });

        return "done";
    }

    public async void MethodA()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            await Task.Delay(200);
        Console.WriteLine("MethodA");

    }
}
```

I guess I need more help on this...

Comment: Whenever you find yourself typing `async void`, and it isn't for an event handler, you are probably doing something wrong. `async` should always return a `Task`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you code behaves as it does is because the Task you start up to call one of the methods will finish on the first `await` in the method because it is `async void` and just continue thus causing the `await Task.Run(new Action(MethodA));` to return control to the thread while your `MethodA` body is still running.  This is because `async void` is basically fire and forget.

Here's what happens in a simplified version of your code.

```
class A
{
    public async Task<string> Method()
    {
        // You create a task to run MethodA
        await Task.Run(new Action(MethodA));
        // control returns here on the first `await` in MethodA because 
        // it is `async void`. 

        return "done";
    }

    public async void MethodA()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MethodA" + i);
            // Here the control is returned to the thread and because 
            // it's `async void` an `await` will only block until you reach
            // this point the first time.
            await Task.Delay(1000); // 
        }
    }
}
```

To get the results you want you first need to return a `Task` from your methods so they can be awaited.  Then you don't need the `Task.Run` either.

```
class A
{
    public async Task<string> Method()
    {
        await MethodA();
        await MethodB();

        return "done";
    }

    public async Task MethodA()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MethodA" + i);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }

    public async Task MethodB()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MethodB" + i);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man but actually I just wanna figure out why my code seems against my knowledge of async/await...

Comment: I've added some explanation on why your code doesn't work the way you expect it to.

Comment: I read your comment carefully and I did try it in the VS and all control shifting is like your comment. What bother me the most is I thought process in the same function after await keyword won't run before the awaitable task finished and that's why await MethodA();await MethodB() can output result in order. But I don't understand why await Task.Run() can make so much difference.

Comment: If you make your methods return a `Task` and then do `await Task.Run(() => await MethodA());` Then it would work because the task you are awaiting is also awaiting `MethodA`.  Basically `Task.Run` was another layer between the `await` and the method, but the primary issue was that the methods were `async void`.

Comment: The reason why it continues is that the function returns void, the caller has no Task from which to know when the async operation is done.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to return Task from MethodA and MethodB, instead of writing to the console IN those methods. Like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new A();

        var result = a.Method();

        Console.Read();
    }
}

class A
{
    public async Task<string> Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(await MethodA());
        Console.WriteLine(await MethodB());

        return "done";
    }

    public async Task<string> MethodA()
    {
        var returnString = string.Empty;
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            returnString += "MethodA" + i + '\n'+'\r';
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
        return returnString;
    }

    public async Task<string> MethodB()
    {
        var returnString = string.Empty;
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            returnString += "MethodB" + i + '\n'+'\r';
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
        return returnString;
    }
}
```

Note: I haven't tested that code, but it should illustrate the general idea.

Answer (score -1):

`async + await != sync`, because of **continuation**

For more details, [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx#BKMK_Threads)

`Async methods` are intended to be non-blocking operations.

`An await expression in an async method doesn’t block the current thread` while the awaited task is running. Instead, the expression signs up the rest of the method as a continuation and returns control to the caller of the `async` method.

Comment: While this is all technically correct, it doesn't really explain the problem with the code in an easily understandable way; especially for someone who is just learning async / await.

Comment: @BradleyUffner hmm.. I agree. Already Mr. juharr gave the relative code. I just tried to give the clear conception of this issue.

Comment: @SkyWalker Thanks. I read it carefully. In the picture in the same page you can see the DoIndependentWork() is before the await keyword and according to my understanding is that await keyword will 'yield return' to calling thread and when the awaitable task is done it will continue from the await keyword. So that's why await MethodA(); await MethodB() can output in expected order(MethodA1,MethodA2...MethodA9 MethodB1..)